# Trouble installing and using Tensorflow and Keras in (Anaconda) Jupyter Notebook in my MacBook Air M1

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Am trying to build a Stacked LSTM model for Stock Price prediction using tensor flow and Keras. So am trying to install tensor flow and keras in my Jupyter notebook. I use a 2020 MacBook Air M1.

First I tried installing it through the Terminal through the following code

`conda create -n tf tensorflow`

The above code worked and the installation was successful. But when I tried to import tensor flow in my Jupyter notebook, I was not able to do so.

Then I tried to install tensor flow and keras directly into Jupyter notebook through the following codes.

`pip install tensorflow`

`pip install keras`

The installations were successful. And I was trying trying to use them to import the library.

`from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential`
`from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense`
`from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM`

The minute I tried to execute this code to import the library the Kernel automatically dies as it says.

Am a noob trying to build my first LSTM Model for a project, so pardon if there are silly mistakes in the steps I tried

[image]

Comment: How are you running Jupyter? There are probably error logs that would help you.

Comment: I run Jupyter using Anaconda. Or is that anything else that you are asking??

Comment: import tensorflow in a python shell (outside jupyter), and report the error when it crashes.